# UIManager.put() not working?

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jslider, uimanager

I'm using an app with JSliders and setting the look and feel to platform default. Now I'm trying to set the slider's thumb size using this code:

```
UIManager.put("Slider.thumbHeight",5);
UIManager.put("Slider.thumbWidth",20);
```

but their size remains unchanged. I've also tried this:

```
UIManager.getDefaults().put("Slider.thumbHeight",5);
UIManager.getDefaults().put("Slider.thumbWidth",20);
```

same result, the thumb on the slider remains the default size. I've also calling that before/after setting the style but there was no difference.

Comment: what is the outcome if you don't use ui manager ?

Comment: there's the default slider style, but it's not changed at all...

Comment: what happened you just do like? Jslider js = newbJSlider() and do the rest. no ui manager at all?

Comment: there's just the basic JSlider, but since the rest of the app is in the system default look and feel it stands out by a lot.